# Can we call a super class constructor from 2nd sub class in multilevel inheritance in java

Tags: java, inheritance

Suppose there are three classes A, B and C. C extends B and B extends A. Can we call class A constructor directly without calling class B constructor in sub class C?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and find out?

Comment: No, always a (possibly implicit) super constructor is called, then all fields initialized and the rest from the constructor executed.

Comment: That makes no sense. A is a subset of B is a subset of C. By calling B, you automatically get A. If you don't want "B," but you want A, then define D extends A as something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  The constructor of a subclass will explicitly or implicitly invoke one of the constructors of its superclass to initialize itself.  Constructors of other classes cannot be invoked (except to initialize different objects) whatever those classes' relationship to the class being initialized may be.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible.
Anyways, if C does not relate to B, but to A, why does C extend B in the first place?

You could also try and create some protected method in A that could be called from both A's and C's constructors.

If you could try and describe what you're trying to model, maybe some alternative hierarchy would be more suitable.

Comment: +one for the suggestion that the questioner describe the problem.  It's impossible to really have a discussion of the problems and the solutions without a concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, although the constructor of child class starts executing first(when you create its object) but there's always a no-arg constructor call to super in the constructor of the child(unless you manually call super with arguments) and so on. Following this hierarchy the constructor of the top most parent class although starts its execution at last, but finishes first!

Answer (score 0):

Not directly .. but something like this can be done:

```
public class A {
   A(){
   ....
   }
}

public class B extends A {
   B(){
   super();
   ....
   }
}

public class C extends B {
   C(){
   super();
   ....
   }
}

// In main()
C c = new C(); // This will eventually call A's constructor
```